# Invalid Kenel Image , GPU Rendering not working on 2.79 but works on 2.78

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, gpu, error

I am running 2.79 on Windows 10 OS on a fairly new machine.

I have a weird issue, a week ago I could render using GPU without problem, but suddenly today on a new model (as well as all others I've tested including the last one to be GPU rendered) rendering doesn't work anymore, giving a kernel image error message.

What is this and how do I resolve it? I have tested GPU render on a number of files plus using 2.78, which works but doesn't support the principled shader.

Comment: Windows 10, you say? First guess is that Updates effed up the GPU drivers. Second guess - your fairly new machine is a laptop with dedicated and internal GPU and somehow Blender doesn't find the GPU anymore. Check "User Preferences - System - Cycles Compute Device" if it still shows up there.

Comment: no laptop only pc.

Comment: yh did that with user prefremces gives me gpu compute i selecet gpu on render then  get the error when i click render / f12

Comment: !!!! it was on the cuda tab with quarda display k600 ticked , i set to none and i could render in gpu !!! does none not use my graphics card ????